# Unclear on install instructions - D10?

Tags: drupal, installation, migration

I've been using CiviCRM on Drupal 7 for many years, and it's time to upgrade my Drupal.

- Drupal 8 went EOL November 2, 2021.
- Drupal 9 goes EOL November 1, 2023, which is in 12 days.

So it looks like Drupal 10 should be the way to go.

I'm starting with a fresh Drupal installation (I have a very minimal website outside of CiviCRM), I don't really need to port any Drupal-level stuff over to the new site.

I went to the relevant installation page https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/ , but the instructions there don't seem to support D10 yet (they ask for pull requests to write such instructions - wish I could help!).

I'm guessing I need to do something like:

```
cd /opt/my-dir
composer remove drush/drush  # Is this still necessary?
composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer config minimum-stability dev
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.55'  # Should this be drupal-10 now?
composer require 'drush/drush:12.*'
```

Does that all seem correct?  CiviCRM 5.55 is my current version.

Once I've done this, what's the best procedure for importing all my data from my current installation?  I see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/ but that also looks quite old, I'm not sure what's best practice.

**UPDATE:** I tried out this technique and I seem to have ended up with CiviCRM 5.66 installed, despite seeing the following in my `composer.json` file:

```
    "require": {
        "civicrm/civicrm-core": "~5.55",
        "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "~5.55",
        "civicrm/civicrm-packages": "~5.55",
```

How can I keep version parity with the site I'm coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the "update" section: perhaps you want to stick to a specific version of CiviCRM package:  using Composer it should be like this (just drop the tilde):

```
 "require": {
    "civicrm/civicrm-core": "5.55",
    "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "5.55",
    "civicrm/civicrm-packages": "5.55",
```

Check for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer) for tech details.

On the separate note: despite of D7 hard EOL announced, I'd stick with it for a bit longer its "expiration date", maybe a few years more. Per my experience, the current state of D8/9/10 and its CiviCRM counterpart doesn't quite worth an upgrade rush, to put it politely.