# CiviCRM installation fails on Drupal 10

Tags: drupal, installation

I am installing CiviCRM on a new server, new Drupal 10. Per [instructions](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/), I ran the following commands:

```
cd /var/www/drupal
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}
composer require civicrm/cv -W
```

Also tried per [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45736/unclear-on-install-instructions-d10) post

```
composer config minimum-stability dev
composer require 'drush/drush:12.*'
```

Got the following error:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - civicrm/cv dev-master requires symfony/process ^4 -> found symfony/process[v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - civicrm/cv[v0.1.0, ..., v0.1.1] require symfony/console ~2.3 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., 2.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - civicrm/cv[v0.1.2, ..., v0.2.1] require symfony/console ~2.8 -> found symfony/console[v2.8.0-BETA1, ..., 2.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - civicrm/cv[dev-colemanw-patch-1, v0.2.2, ..., v0.3.13] require symfony/console ~2.8|^3 -> found symfony/console[v2.8.0-BETA1, ..., 2.8.x-dev, v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - civicrm/cv[v0.3.14, ..., v0.3.48] require symfony/console ^4 -> found symfony/console[v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires civicrm/cv * -> satisfiable by civicrm/cv[dev-master, dev-colemanw-patch-1, v0.1.0, ..., v0.3.48].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require civicrm/cv:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require civicrm/cv:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

```
PHP 8.2.9
Drupal 10.2.0
Amazon Linux 2023
Apache 2.4.5.8
Composer 2.6.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Instructions have been [fixed](https://lab.civicrm.org/documentation/docs/installation/-/merge_requests/64), although I still personally think you'll get better results with the phar, and `cv` is generally something you want to install for all the sites on the server so only needs one copy.

---

I know the instructions say it but I wouldn't try to install cv this way for drupal 9/10. Use the [phar](https://download.civicrm.org/cv/cv.phar) download of cv rather than trying to get it with composer.

Comment: I got some strange error with `phar`; I'll research later and try composer with cli-tools as well

Comment: it worked with cli-tools. Got a few glitches (my password had characters that `mysql_connect` choked; and `cv core:install` was running under user id, but drupal created files under apache. But nothing that couldn't be fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
composer require civicrm/cv -W
```

use

```
composer require civicrm/cli-tools
```

as in the updated Installation Guide (see post of @Demerit above).
Then, you have to add your `vendor/bin` directory to `$PATH`.
This worked for me recently.

Comment: yes, it work with cli-tools. I didn't need to add `vendor/bin` to path